# Only 2 related products are showing in backend

Tags: magento2.2

Only two products are displaying as recommended product in magento product admin grid whereas we have assign 10 product with a product as recommended product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the default issue of magento, can be resolved by changing the following file with mentioned changes.

Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\CollectionProvider on method getCollection

```
foreach ($output as $item) {
        $itemPosition = (int)$item['position'];
        while(true) {
            if (!isset($sorterItems[$itemPosition])) {
                break;
            }
            $itemPosition += 1;
        }
        $sorterItems[$itemPosition] = $item;
    }
```